# Regular expression ([-(?!\[|\]|\ )09XYAB\[\]\-]){0,} not working

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Regex must fulfill the following conditions:

- Allowed characters `09XYAB[]-`
- After a '`-`' I cannot have a space, a  '`]`' or '`[`'
- Furthermore I will have to check the order of the brackets.

I've written this expression '`([-(?!\[|\]|\ )09XYAB\[\]\-]){0,}`' but I keep getting the fault results on lets say this test string '`ABY-Ab[A0-]`'.

Comment: Do you mean each opening bracket must have a closing bracket, and can brackets be nested ? What language are you using ?

Comment: Yes, means each opening should have a closing and they can be nested as well. I'm using javascript to test, I'm testing it on [link](http://regexpal.com/) @Sniffer

Comment: This can't be done with Javascript's regex engine so you will have to parse this expression manually.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `^([09XYAB\[\]]|(-(?![ \[\]])))+$`

this part `[09XYAB\[\]]` catch `09XYAB[]`
this part `(-(?![ \[\]])))` catch `-` and `[]` or space cant be next symbol

alas it regex can't check the order, it's hard task for regex, it's not for this purpose

Comment: Well, yeah i was about to write it down that it doesn't satisfy the order of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

How abou:

```
^(?!-[\[\]])[09XYAB\[\]-]+$
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?!-[ \[\]])[09XYAB\[\]-]+$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ \[\]]                  any character of: ' ', '\[', '\]'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [09XYAB\[\]-]+           any character of: '0', '9', 'X', 'Y', 'A',
                           'B', '\[', '\]', '-' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you forgot space after dash

Comment: I thought of this but what about the order of the brackets and the possibility of brackets being nested, he didn't specify the language !

Comment: Language: Javascript.
Actually what i'm trying to do is, Each opening should have a closing and they can be nested as well.

Comment: @MirzaAliBaig: Forget my answer as it doesn't work with javascript (look ahead), and regex is not the good tool to deal with nested brackets.

Answer (score 0):

@burning_LEGION's answer correctly provides the first half of the solution. This answer provides the second half; validating matching bracket pairs, even when they are nested. @Sniffer is correct that it can't be done with a single regex. However, correctly parsing the nested structure can be done fairly easily using a JavaScript regex by parsing from the inside out...

### JavaScript Solution [for [Nested] Brackets]

Since JavaScript regex syntax does not provide recursive expressions, it is impossible to match the outermost pair of matching brackets when the brackets are nested. However, it is quite easy to write a regex which correctly matches an *innermost* pair of matching brackets:

### `/\[[^[\]]*\]/g`

The tested JavaScript function below validates proper bracket pair matching for strings that may have nested bracket pairs. It does so by iteratively stripping out matching innermost bracket pairs from the inside out using the above regex. Once all the (possibly nested) matching pairs have been removed, any remaining bracket characters indicate that the string has invalid bracket matching.

```js
function validBracketNesting(text) {
    // Regex to match innermost matching brackets
    var re_innerbrackets = /\[[^[\]]*\]/g;
    // Iterate stripping matching bracket pairs from inside out.
    while (text.search(re_innerbrackets) !== -1) {
        text = text.replace(re_innerbrackets, '');
    } // All (possibly nested) matching bracket pairs removed.
    // Any remaining bracket indicates invalid bracket pairing.
    return (text.match(/[[\]]/)) ? false : true;
}
```